# Kendo Grid Export To Excel Currency formatting

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to export my Kendo grid to excel. It works fine except the formatting is missing. I think it is because I am using a template.

[The Telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/how-to/Export/cell-format) explicitly states:

> To format the cell values during the export of the Grid to Excel, set
>   the format option of the cells.

I have tried this and it is not working:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: "EntryWage",
        headerTemplate: entryLevelWageColumnHeading + "<span name='EntryWage' class='k-icon k-i-close remove' style='float: right;'></span>",
        width: 125,
        attributes: { style: "text-align:right;" },
        format: "{0:c}",
        template: "#= (EntryWage != null) ? kendo.toString(EntryWage, 'C') : 'N/A' #"
    }];
```

I also have this function (for excel grid defintiion):

```
    excelExport: function (e) {
        var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
        var row = sheet.rows[0];
        $("#grid .k-grid-header .k-link").each(function (index) { //for each column header in the grid...
            row.cells[index].value = $(this).text(); //set cell text from grid column text
            row.cells[index].background = "#0070C0"; //set cell to "blue" color
        });
    },
```

Do I need to parse each cell here? Am I doing something wrong? I would think this would be really simple, since the whole Export to Excel is straightforward??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `template` should have any effect on the data being exported (as the `excelExport` is based on the `dataSource`).

Here is a jsFiddle of a [working example of `excelExport`](https://jsfiddle.net/dwosrs0x/35/) which changes the formatting of each `cell`.

Note the difference between the `excelExport` code:

```
excelExport: function(e) {      
  var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];        
    for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex++) {
        var cell = row.cells[cellIndex];
        if (row.type === "data") {
            //if (cellIndex == 2) { 
            if (sheet.rows[0].cells[cellIndex].value == "unitPrice") {// like this
                cell.format = "number";
                cell.background = "#0070C0"
                cell.hAlign = "right";
            }
        }
    }      
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy suggestion. I ended up solving it similarly (see below).

Answer (score 4):

I ended up solving it similarly to Sandman's suggestion. I based my output format on the field name, from each column (input).

I also append the grid's column headers to the Excel column header row. It's a little sad Kendo doesn't already do this.

```
excelExport: function (e) {  
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    var row = sheet.rows[0];

    //Excel output - create a header row
    $("#grid .k-grid-header .k-link").each(function (index) { //for each column header in the grid...
        row.cells[index].value = $(this).text(); //set cell text from grid column text
        row.cells[index].background = "#0070C0"; //set cell to "blue" color
    });

    //Excel output - column formatting
    var formatMask = null;
    for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) { //begin on first row (skip header)
        row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
        for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex++) { //for each row, check each cell by field name
            switch (this.columns[cellIndex].field) {
                case "Field1":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field2":
                    formatMask = "$#,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field3":
                    formatMask = "$#,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field4":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field5":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field6":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field7":
                    formatMask = null;
                    row.cells[cellIndex].value = row.cells[cellIndex].value;
                    break;
                case "Field8":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field9":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field10":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field11":
                    formatMask = "###,##0";
                    break;
                case "Field12":
                    if (row.cells[cellIndex].value === false) {
                        row.cells[cellIndex].value = "No";
                    } else {
                        row.cells[cellIndex].value = "Yes";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            row.cells[cellIndex].format = formatMask; //apply column format mask
        }

    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

We needed a bit more flexibility so we created an excelTemplate property for  some columns and during the excelExport use that to update the cell values.

```
{
    field: 'AppId',
    title: 'Application',
    width: '99px',
    template: function(data) {
        return _applications()[data.AppId].Name;
    },
    excelTemplate: function(data) {
        return _applications()[data].Name;
    },
    groupHeaderTemplate: function(data) {
        return _applications()[data.value].Name;
    },
},
```

1. Look though the columns for the excelTemplate property
2. Find the header row and then match the column title to the
   header row title to build an associative array
3. Update the templated cell values for all the rows.

```js
function(e) {
    var templatesByTitle = {};
    var columnTemplates = [];
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

    this.columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.excelTemplate) {
            templatesByTitle[column.title] = column.excelTemplate;
        }
    })

    for (var r = 0; r < sheet.rows.length; r++) {
        var row = sheet.rows[r];
        if (row.type === "header") {
            row.cells.forEach(function(headerCell, index) {
                var template = templatesByTitle[headerCell.value];
                if (template !== undefined) {
                    columnTemplates.push({
                        column: index,
                        template: template
                    });
                }
            })
            break;
        }
    }

    sheet.rows.forEach(function(row) {
        if (row.type === "data") {
            columnTemplates.forEach(function(columnTemplate) {
                var cell = row.cells[columnTemplate.column];
                if (cell.value !== null) {
                    cell.value = columnTemplate.template(cell.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```